# error SIGABRT - Cannot load multiple arrays in my TableViewController

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I am trying to load multiple food menu arrays into one TableViewController. The main menu displays 2 buttons, 1: breakfast menu 2: bakery menu. Every time I press on of them the simulator crashes and shows the SIGABRT error. After a sleepless night of trying it myself I am reaching out to you to have a look at it.... I checked all connections and buttons with segues and it all checks out..

My cell has 3 labels and an image with each their own array. I divided the buttons to select in different content modes. Content mode 1: breakfast & Content mode 2: bakery..

Sorry guys just really want to learn how to do this!

**Button Menu Controller:**

```
import UIKit
```

class foodMenuController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainMenuButton: UIButton!

var contentMode = 0

//Breakfast mode
@IBAction func breakfastButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    contentMode == 1

}

//Bakery mode
@IBAction func bakeryButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    contentMode = 2
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    //Hide navigation bar
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true


     func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

}
```

**TABLEVIEWCONTROLLER**

```
import UIKit
```

class breakfastFoodControllerTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
//Return to Food Menu
@IBOutlet weak var returnButton: UIBarButtonItem!


// BREAKFAST MENU
let breakfastMenu = ["SAVORY CROISSANT", "HEARTY CROISSANT", "LE PETIT DÉJEUNER", "BREAKFAST in AMERICA", "SCRAMBLED EGGS", "FRESH FRUIT BOWL", "OMELETTE", "OATMEAL CUP", "PARIS SANDWICH", "EGGS BENEDICT", "CHEESE BAGEL", "EGGS BALTIQUE", "TOASTED BAGEL", "TOAST"]

// Breakfast menu images
let breakfastMenuImages = ["SAVORY CROISSANT.bmp", "HEARTY CROISSANT.bmp", "LE PETIT DÉJEUNER.bmp", "BREAKFAST in AMERICA.bmp", "SCRAMBLED EGGS.bmp", "FRESH FRUIT BOWL.bmp", "OMELETTE.bmp", "OATMEAL CUP.bmp", "PARIS SANDWICH.bmp", "EGGS BENEDICT.bmp", "CHEESE BAGEL", "EGGS BALTIQUE.bmp", "TOASTED BAGEL.bmp", "TOAST.bmp"]

// Meals definition
let breakfastMealDefined = ["Stuffed with eggs, ham and swiss cheese", "Stuffed with eggs, bacon and swiss cheese", "French baguette with butter, jam", "Two eggs, bacon, sausage, roasted potatoes","Scrambled eggs & smoked salmon","Seasonal fruits with a honey yogurt dressing.","Three fluffy eggs. Add 70 cents per ingredient choice:","Warm oatmeal with milk & extra's","French baguette with ham, cheese & butter","Two poached eggs on an English muffin","Toasted bagel with cream cheese and smoked salmon","Two poached eggs on an English muffin","Toasted bagel with cream cheese & jam","Choose from white, wheat or rye with jelly"]

// Meal price
var breakfastPrice = ["$8,25","$8,25","$7,25","$9,95","$9,25","$5,95","$7,95","$3,95","$9,25","$9,50","$10,25","$11,95","$3,75","$2,75"]

//BAKERY MENU
let bakeryMenu = ["SAVORY CROISSANT", "HEARTY CROISSANT", "LE PETIT DÉJEUNER"]

//Bakery menu images
let bakeryMenuImages = ["SAVORY CROISSANT.bmp", "HEARTY CROISSANT.bmp", "LE PETIT DÉJEUNER.bmp"]

// Bakery definition
let bakeryMealDefined = ["Stuffed with eggs, ham and swiss cheese", "Stuffed with eggs, bacon and swiss cheese", "French baguette with butter, jam"]

// Meal price
var bakeryPrice = ["$8,25","$8,25","$7,25"]


// -->   VIEW DID LOAD <-- //
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if foodMenuController().contentMode == 1 {
        return breakfastMenu.count
    }
    if foodMenuController().contentMode == 2 {
        return bakeryMenu.count
    } else{

    return foodMenuController().contentMode; 1
}
}

// CONTENT MODE 1

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as! firstTableViewSettings

    if foodMenuController().contentMode == 1 {

        // Cell Configuration (image, text labels, round images)

        cell.menuImageOption.image = UIImage (named: breakfastMenu[indexPath.row])
        cell.mealPrice.text = breakfastPrice[indexPath.row]
        cell.mealDescription.text = breakfastMealDefined[indexPath.row]
        cell.menuChoicelabel.text = breakfastMenu[indexPath.row]
        cell.menuImageOption.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0
        cell.menuImageOption.clipsToBounds = true

    }


//CONTENT MODE 2

       if foodMenuController().contentMode == 2 {

            // Cell Configuration (image, text labels, round images)

            cell.menuImageOption.image = UIImage (named: bakeryMenu[indexPath.row])
            cell.mealPrice.text = bakeryPrice[indexPath.row]
            cell.mealDescription.text = bakeryMealDefined[indexPath.row]
            cell.menuChoicelabel.text = bakeryMenu[indexPath.row]
            cell.menuImageOption.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0
            cell.menuImageOption.clipsToBounds = true
        }

       return cell

        }
    }
```

**TABLEVIEWCELL**

```
import UIKit
```

class firstTableViewSettings: UITableViewCell {

```
// Outlets for prototype cell configuration


@IBOutlet weak var menuImageOption: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var menuChoicelabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mealDescription: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mealPrice: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Comment: contentMode == 1 ?  one too many '=', I think

Comment: also - you may want to have a look at defining a class or struct to hold your menu data, and then having a single array to hold that, rather than maintaining several arrays.

Comment: and then - your breakfast and bakery data structures are identical - if you used a 2-D array (breakfast = index 0, bakery = index 1) then you only need one set of code in the tableview methods to handle everything

Comment: The main problem is the use of `...foodMenuController()...` in your tableView controller.  This creates a new instance of `foodMenuController` - it does not access the existing instance.  The solution depends on how the two view controllers are related.  Edit your post to explain how they are related - which is displayed first, how and when is the other displayed?

Comment: @pbasdf - one viewcontroller that is the foodMenuController which has 2 buttons displayed. breakfast & bakery, in the foodMenuController I defined 2 different contentModes for this 1 & 2. Both buttons segue to show the tableViewController which should load either the breakfast arrays, or the bakery arrays. However, when I click on either buttons the simulator crashes and I can figure out why? Hope this helps explaining it a bit? 

Does anyone have a file like this? loading different arrays in a table when a button is clicked in a viewcontroller? just to look at as an example to email me?

Comment: @ Kevin Start by reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/3985749) about passing data between view controllers.  The code is Objective-C, but you should be able to see what is going on, and the principles are the same for Swift.  In your case, you need to pass the data forward from `FoodMenuController` to `BreakfastFoodControllerTableViewController`.  This is best done using `prepareForSegue`.  I'll try to post a full answer later.

Comment: @pbasdf thanks i really appreciate it. Once i know the technique on how to load different arrays in a tableviewcontroller when a button is clicked in the first viewcontroller I can continue building my app. I hope you can post a answer for me! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is easier to pass data forward, to the next view controller, than it is to get the data from a previous view controller.  So, move `contentMode` to the `BreakfastFoodControllerTableViewController` (which makes sense; it determines the "mode" of the TVC).

```
var contentMode = 0
```

Then amend every reference of `foodMenuController().contentMode` to just `contentMode`.

Next, amend the `FoodMenuController` to set the correct value immediately before the segue to the `BreakfastFoodControllerTableViewController`.  The place to do this is in the `FooodMenuController`'s `prepareForSegue` method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let breakfastVC = segue.destinationViewController as! BreakfastFoodControllerTableViewController
    if segue.identifier == "showBreakfast" {
        breakfastVC.contentMode = 1
    } else if segue.identifier == "showBakery" {
        breakfastVC.contentMode = 2
    }
}
```

You will need to ensure that each segue has the correct identifier in your storyboard:

[image]

The `IBAction` methods `breakfastButton` and `bakeryButton` are no longer required.

Comment: I tried your method...however, the contentMode in the TV controller is not changing its value to 1 or 2 when the button is pressed. Am i missing something?

Comment: Difficult to say - can you edit your post to show your current code?

Comment: @Kevin Any luck with this?

Comment: Sorry for not replying back to this. I used your method but had to get some extra help from other people. It worked out in the end though! so thank you very much :)

Comment: @Kevin No problem; glad you got it sorted.